# Closing Lightbox when clicking elsewhere on page

Tags: javascript, html, lightbox

I am trying to design a website using a CC template and am trying to implement a Lightbox as per: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_lightbox

The lightbox displays fine, but the problem I'm having is if I click outside the lightbox, nothing happens - and there is no close button either.

I am very elementary with JavaScript and web development in general so please be gentle.

This is the lightbox code pulled from w3schools, I modified it to use my own images and added the colwrap div so I could position the images side-by-side:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
<span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
<div class="modal-content">

<div class="mySlides">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
  <img src="images/team/test2.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
  <img src="images/team/test3.jpg"  style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
  <img src="images/team/test4.jpg"  style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides">
  <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
  <img src="images/team/test5.jpg"  style="width:100%">
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

<div class="caption-container">
  <p id="caption"></p>
</div>

<div id="colwrap">

  <img class="demo cursor" src="images/team/test2.jpg" style="width:20%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="Jacob Wilson - Vocals">


  <img class="demo cursor" src="images/team/test3.jpg" style="width:20%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Kevin Lee - Lead Guitar">


  <img class="demo cursor" src="images/team/test4.jpg" style="width:22%; height:5%;" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="Jeff Bridges - Drums">


  <img class="demo cursor" src="images/team/test5.jpg" style="width:20%" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="Shikamaru Nara - Bass">

  </div>
```

And this is the JavaScript to close the modal:

`function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "none";
}`

So at the moment there is no close icon and clicking outside does nothing either. However, if I change this line:

```
<span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
```

To span any class that isn't "close cursor" there will be a tiny X in the top left of the modal that you can use to close the lightbox. I don't really get what that line is doing, because I can set it to span a class that doesn't exist and it will still give that little X. But if it's close cursor I don't get that X.

Sorry for the poor formatted post, I wasn't really sure what code to include because it is quite lengthy. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a function named `stopPropagation()` call from event object:

I had change 2 function from this demo:

```
function plusSlides(event, n) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}
function currentSlide(event, n) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}
```

and  html at:
    `<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(event, -1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(event, 1)">&#10095;</a>`

same at:
    `<div class="column">
          <img class="demo cursor" src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%"     onclick="currentSlide(event, 1)" alt="Nature and sunrise">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <img class="demo cursor" src="img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(event, 2)" alt="Trolltunga, Norway">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <img class="demo cursor" src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(event, 3)" alt="Mountains and fjords">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <img class="demo cursor" src="img_lights_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(event, 4)" alt="Northern Lights">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>`

next, I move `closeModal` to parent div

`<div id="myModal" class="modal" onclick="closeModal()">
  <span class="close cursor">&times;</span>`

it work fine!

link demo for you at [here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FFRQHW7BFVQD)! hope this can help!

Answer (score 0):

**Check the snippet hope it will help.**

```js
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "none";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}
$(document).mouseup(function(e){
  if($(e.target).parents('.modal-content').length==0 && !$(e.target).is('.modal-content')){
   $('.modal').css('display', 'none');
  }
 });
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row > .column {
  padding: 0 8px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: black;
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

img {
  margin-bottom: -4px;
}

.caption-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: white;
}

.demo {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

img.hover-shadow {
  transition: 0.3s
}

.hover-shadow:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19)
}
```

```html
<h2 style="text-align:center">Lightbox</h2>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(3)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(4)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
  <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    
    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

    <div class="caption-container">
      <p id="caption"></p>
    </div>


    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="Nature and sunrise">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Trolltunga, Norway">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="Mountains and fjords">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="Northern Lights">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Click the outside of `modal` or `lightbox` content [view this link](http://prntscr.com/f9xzuw)

Additional file add Google `ajax`.

jQuery Script for closing `modal` or `lightbox` when user click outside of `modal-content`.

```
$(document).mouseup(function(e){
            if($(e.target).parents('.modal-content').length==0 && !$(e.target).is('.modal-content')){
                $('.modal').css('display', 'none');
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the event when someone clicks outside and close the modal.

Try this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    body {
      font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
      margin: 0;
    }

    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .row > .column {
      padding: 0 8px;
    }

    .row:after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }

    .column {
      float: left;
      width: 25%;
    }

    /* The Modal (background) */
    .modal {
      display: none;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1;
      padding-top: 100px;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: auto;
      background-color: black;
    }

    /* Modal Content */
    .modal-content {
      position: relative;
      background-color: #fefefe;
      margin: auto;
      padding: 0;
      width: 90%;
      max-width: 1200px;
    }

    /* The Close Button */
    .close {
      color: white;
      position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
      right: 25px;
      font-size: 35px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    .close:hover,
    .close:focus {
      color: #999;
      text-decoration: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .mySlides {
      display: none;
    }

    .cursor {
      cursor: pointer
    }

    /* Next & previous buttons */
    .prev,
    .next {
      cursor: pointer;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      width: auto;
      padding: 16px;
      margin-top: -50px;
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 20px;
      transition: 0.6s ease;
      border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
      user-select: none;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
    }

    /* Position the "next button" to the right */
    .next {
      right: 0;
      border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    }

    /* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
    .prev:hover,
    .next:hover {
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    }

    /* Number text (1/3 etc) */
    .numbertext {
      color: #f2f2f2;
      font-size: 12px;
      padding: 8px 12px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
    }

    img {
      margin-bottom: -4px;
    }

    .caption-container {
      text-align: center;
      background-color: black;
      padding: 2px 16px;
      color: white;
    }

    .demo {
      opacity: 0.6;
    }

    .active,
    .demo:hover {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    img.hover-shadow {
      transition: 0.3s
    }

    .hover-shadow:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19)
    }
    </style>
    <body>

    <h2 style="text-align:center">Lightbox</h2>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
        <img src="1.png" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal(event);currentSlide(event,1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img src="2.jpeg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal(event);currentSlide(event,2)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img src="3.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal(event);currentSlide(event,3)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img src="4.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal(event);currentSlide(event,4)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal(event)">&times;</span>
      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="mySlides">
          <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
          <img src="1.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides">
          <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
          <img src="2.jpeg" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides">
          <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
          <img src="3.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides">
          <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
          <img src="4.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(event, -1)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(event, 1)">&#10095;</a>

        <div class="caption-container">
          <p id="caption"></p>
        </div>


        <div class="column">
          <img class="demo cursor" src="1.png" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(event,1)" alt="Nature and sunrise">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <img class="demo cursor" src="2.jpeg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(event,2)" alt="Trolltunga, Norway">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <img class="demo cursor" src="3.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(event, 3)" alt="Mountains and fjords">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <img class="demo cursor" src="4.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(event,4)" alt="Northern Lights">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
    window.addEventListener('click', clickedOutside, false);
    function clickedOutside(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        closeModal() ;
    }
    function openModal(event) {
       event.stopPropagation();
        document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block";
    }

    function closeModal(event) {
      document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "none";
    }

    var slideIndex = 1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);

    function plusSlides(event,n) {
       event.stopPropagation();
        showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function currentSlide(event,n) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }


    function showSlides(n) {
      var i;
      var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
      var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
      if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
      if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
      for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
          slides[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
          dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
      slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
      dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
      captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```